# Scripting.FileSystemObject location (from JavaScript)

Tags: directory, filesystemobject, windows-desktop-gadgets

I have a file for my Windows sidebar gadget that stores some settings for the user, but the FSO object seems to pick its native residence as the desktop, meaning that if I don't specify a directory, it will put this file on the desktop.  I would specify the whole location, but I want to be able to put this on other people's computers without having stuff on their desktop or elsewhere besides the gadget folder.

I know this is possible in XMLHttpRequest, but I've had trouble with that in the past, and it would be better if I could just avoid it altogether, if possible.

```
function writeSetting(text)
{
    var fil = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var writer = fil.OpenTextFile("loc.txt", 2, true);
    writer.WriteLine(text);
    writer.Close();

}
```

Comment: is this for a desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`System.Gadget.path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to get the gadget's path and append to it as needed. See the example in the link.

Happy coding.